# All files of folder modified specific date to till

Tags: find

Please help me to search the modified files since September 2013 to till date. using find command in Linux which also ignore `.svn` hidden directories .

Comment: plz check it below command is correct are not ? find . -type d -name .svn -prune -o -mtime -220 -type f -print

Answer (score 0):

find . *.* -mtime -180 | xargs tar -rfc HalfYear_incremental.tar

Comment: thank you very much for reply .But how to omitted the .svn folder ?